# Double quotes inside array

Tags: php, arrays, double-quotes

I have this line of code in my file, but in the return array part, I need to have double quotes inside the array.

If I leave the way it is right now, it crashes.

How can I solve this problem?

```
if ($number_of_picture_allowed <= $number_of_picture)
        return array('error' => "{tr domain="PhrasesInTemplates"}You already selected the maximum amount of pictures for this shirt!{/tr}",'file_sid' => $fileSid);
```

Thanks in advace,
Arky

Comment: Did you read documentation about [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something about the Smarty syntax there.. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape those quotes using the backslash (`\`). Hence your return should look:

```
return array('error' => "{tr domain=\"PhrasesInTemplates\"}You already selected the maximum amount of pictures for this shirt!{/tr}",'file_sid' => $fileSid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes inside the array using \

```
    return array('error' => "{tr domain=\"PhrasesInTemplates\"}You already selected the maximum amount of pictures for this shirt!{/tr}",'file_sid' => $fileSid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($number_of_picture_allowed <= $number_of_picture)
    return array('error' => "{tr domain=\"PhrasesInTemplates\"}You already selected the maximum amount of pictures for this shirt!{/tr}",'file_sid' => $fileSid);
```

Try this. [PHP Double Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Wrap the content in single quotes
   `$arr  = array('error' => '{tr domain="PhrasesInTemplates"}You already selected the maximum amount of pictures for this shirt!{/tr}','file_sid' => $fileSid);`
2. Escape quotes using backslash(\) \"